# Mysql Query: Find Customer W/Orders but without Payment

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, inner-query

As the title says, i am trying to find the customer's who have made orders but have not made payments yet.

I have Three tables;

```
Customers, Payments, Orders
```

The sql i have so far gives me (nested query) all the customers without payments, the outer query then tries to join all the customers with orders and checks if those customers are not in my inner table?

```
SELECT customerWOpayments.customerNumber FROM 
ClassicModels.Customers c
INNER JOIN ClassicModels.Orders o ON c.customerName = o.customerNumber
NOT IN 
(SELECT  distinct c.customerNumber
FROM ClassicModels.Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassicModels.Payments p ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
WHERE p.customerNumber IS NULL) customerWOpayments;
```

I am getting a mysql syntax error at line 8 but cannot figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return customers who have orders but no matching payment assuming all of the keys you joined on in your original example were correct (for example c.customerName = o.customerNumber seems suspicious).

```
SELECT c.customerNumber
FROM ClassicModels.Customers c
  INNER JOIN ClassicModels.Orders o
    ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassicModels.Payments p
    ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
WHERE p.customerNumber IS NULL;
```

Comment: Your absolutely right about c.customerName, that was a typo it should be c.customerNumber instead. I am trying your implementation now

Answer (score 1):

Basically you missed the `WHERE` clause. And your question lacks information. Please provide the `Schema` of your tables. Thanks!

try this one:

Are you sure with this condition `ON c.customerName = o.customerNumber`?

```
SELECT customerWOpayments.customerNumber 
FROM  ClassicModels.Customers c INNER JOIN ClassicModels.Orders o 
         ON c.customerName = o.customerNumber -- Please check this out
WHERE o.customerNumber NOT IN 
    (SELECT  distinct c.customerNumber
    FROM ClassicModels.Customers c LEFT JOIN ClassicModels.Payments p 
             ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
    WHERE p.customerNumber IS NULL);
```

OR Without Subquery

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Customers a INNER JOIN Orders b ON
        a.CustomerName = b.CustomerNumber -- Please check this line
     LEFT JOIN Payments c ON
        b.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
WHERE c.CustomerNumber IS NULL
```

I believe it's a typo error on `a.CustomerName = b.CustomerNumber`, instead `a.CustomerNumber = b.CustomerNumber`

I can't tell exactly if it is because you didn't provide the `schema` of your tables with some `dummy records`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @warz, Did you try this solution? The second one.

Comment: i tried your second solution, does it what it's suppose to. upvote for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other solutions, this solution will not produce duplicate customer numbers when customers have more than one order.

```
SELECT C.customerNumber 
FROM ClassicModels.Customers C 
WHERE 
EXISTS(
    -- customer has orders
    SELECT * 
    FROM ClassicModels.Orders AS O
    WHERE O.customerNumber = C.customerNumber 
)
AND NOT EXISTS(
    -- customer does not have payments
    SELECT *
    FROM ClassicModels.Payments P
    WHERE P.customerNumber = C.customerNumber
)
```